# Can someone help me with understanding "The Quiz Problem" from Bertsekas Probability Book

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

I'm struggling with understanding how to answer this question. Can someone help me with an intuitive answer? The answer in the book isn't too clear (to me at least).

> Consider a quiz contest where a person is given a list of $n$ questions and can answer these questions in any order he or she chooses.

> Question $i$ will be answered correctly with probability $P_i$ and the person will then
> receive a reward $V_i$.

> At the first incorrect answer, the quiz terminates and the person
> is allowed to keep his or her previous rewards.

> The problem is to choose the ordering
> of questions so as to maximize the expected value of the total reward obtained.

> Show
> that it is optimal to answer questions in a non-increasing order of $P_i \times \dfrac{V_i}{1 - P_i}.$

I think I understand the core of this question from a high level which is that :

- Yes, you want to answer questions in the order of highest expected value to lowest.
- That's common sense, since at any given step you want to maximize your chances of the game not ending.

But beyond that I don't really know how to show it.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to express the Math in a MathSE posting.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you play the natures order. Then the expected contribution of the $i$th question is
$E_i=P_1P_2\cdots P_iV_i$.
If you swap two consecutive questions $k$ and $k+1$, only $E_k$ and $E_{k+1}$ change to some $E_k’$ and $E_{k+1}’$. If you write down the condition $E_k’+E_{k+1}’\le E_k+E_{k+1}$, simplify, and separate indices $k$ and $k+1$, the claim emerges.

By the way, neither do you optimally start with the highest expected value (i.e., maximise $P_iV_i$), nor the chance of the game not ending (i.e., $P_i$).

Answer (score 0):

I will note $R_i$ this value $R_i = \frac{P_i \times V_i}{1-P_i}$

Consider that at any step, for 2 consécutives question, you have $R_i < R_{i+1}$

You should be able to show that it is not optimum, and by switching these 2 questions, you improve your mean.